# In Office 2016, how can I make buttons from the ribbon's Add-ins->Custom Toolbars group available on the "Home" tab?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-office-2016, ribbon, outlook-addin

Our organization depends on a large number of Add-ins for Microsoft Office.  The buttons for a handful of those Add-ins seem to be available only in a group called "Custom Toolbars" on the "Add-Ins" tab of the ribbon.  There are two problems with this:

1. Users don't think to look in "Add-ins".
2. Some of these commands are used very frequently so the extra click required to access them on the "Add-Ins" tab undermines productivity.

Here are buttons from [one such Add-in](http://spambayes.sourceforge.net/) to demonstrate:

[image: Office 2016 Ribbon Add-in Tab]

Note that those buttons do not appear on the "Home" tab or anywhere else.

Neither the group, buttons, nor the commands seem to be customizable in Outlook 2016.  The commands do not appear in the command list and the group is greyed out in the "Customize Ribbon" window:

[image: Office 2016 Customize Ribbon]

In contrast, those same buttons are always visible in Outlook 2007:

[image: Office 2007 Toolbars]

In Office 2016, is there a way to access those commands from a more prominent location like the "Home" tab?